# How to share data between parent and child components in Angular for easier unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-ui-router, components

I have a main component which is a matrix full of information. Selections can be made across the header items as well as the left rows(first column items). When selections are made both right and left sidebars have different options and statistics that can be worked with.

```
class ParentComponent { } 
class SelectedCategoryComponent { } 
class SelectedRoleComponent { } 
class OtherComponent { }
```

Given that the sidebars use related data to the selections, what would be the best way to share the information?

One way would be to use named router-outlets for the side bars. This would be mean that any requests would be made on component loading and in fact reusing the layout can become complicated without using named router-outlets in this scenario. This would allow for navigating back to previous states and may make unit testing a little easier to manage with fewer data dependencies. The downside seems that the routing will be more challenging.

```
class ParentComponent { } 

// id is passed to the components via named router-outlets
class SelectedCategoryComponent { } 
class SelectedRoleComponent { } 
class OtherComponent { }
```

Now, if I take the path of using parent-component/child-component relationship I think it may be harder to test since there are data dependencies. The back and forth communication may be a little trickier to implement as well as the layout having to be hard-coded into the parent view.

```
// All hosted on the same page
class ParentComponent { } 
class SelectedCategoryComponent { } 
class SelectedRoleComponent { } 
class OtherComponent { } 

@Injectable({...})
class SharedDataService 
{ 
   sharedState: T;
}
```

What is the best way to connect these components as the user interface increases in complexity to ensure easiest possible unit-testing experience?